# How to stream and map a one-to-many relationship?

Tags: java, collections, java-8, java-stream

Say I have the following 2 objects:

```
public class MasterObject {
  Long masterId;
  Long detailId;
  String attribute1;
  //...
}

public class DetailObject {
  Long detailId;
  String attribute2;
  //..
}
```

I have a superset list of 10 master objects, and a subset list of 2 detail objects. In the end, I need a new set of 10 detail objects (copying information from the master), with the appropriate detail Id, after I've verified that attribute1 == attribute2. For each detail object, I need to create a new master object. This is what I've come up with so far, but it's incorrect. Please note my comment block:

```
List<DetailObject> updatedDetails = masterObjects.stream()
  .filter(master -> {
    return detail.stream()
      .anyMatch(it -> master.getAttribute1() == detail.getAttribute2());
  })
  .map(master -> {
    DetailObject detailObject = new DetailObject();
    // Here is where I thought I could set the master Id in the detail object,
    // but I no longer have access to the original detail stream
     return detailObject;
   })
  .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

I'm pretty sure I need to do something after the filter, but filter of course returns just a boolean, when I need the object itself. What to do??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I & my co-worker found a solution to my problem. It looks like this:

```
List<DetailObject> newDetails = details.stream()
  .map(detail -> {
    return masters.stream()
      .filter(master -> filterLoans(detail, master))
      .map(master -> createDetail(detail, master))
      .collect(Collectors.toList());
  })
  .flatMap(List::stream)
  .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Answer (score 3):

I don't really understand your strategy. In particular, there is no instruction at all that modifies the masterId of a DetailObject, and you're creating new DetailObject instances although I don't see any reason to do that.

Moreover, you're comparing Strings with `==`.

Why don't you just loop through the details, and for each detail, find the master which has the same attribute, and if found, update the detail's masterId?

```
details.forEach(
    d -> masters.stream() 
                .filter(m -> m.getAttribute1().equals(d.getAttribute2()))
                .findAny()
                .ifPresent(m -> d.setMasterId(m.masterId)));
```

This is O(m * n), but for m and n being 2 and 10, it really doesn't matter.

You could also just use loops:

```
for (Master m : masters) {
    for (Detail d : details) {
        if (m.getAttribute1().equals(d.getAttribute2())) {
            d.setMasterId(m.getMasterId());
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, the == was just shorthand. I know I should just .equals(). I think you're simple solution is what I needed! I just got wrapped around myself with all the streams...

Comment: The content assist isn't allowing me to invoke ifPresent after findAny().

Comment: Then either your content assist is messed up, or there is a problem in your code. findAny() returns an Optional, and Optional has a ifPresent() method. Post your code, compile it, and post the exact and complete error message from the compiler.

Comment: I got the syntax problem fixed. Thank you!

Comment: I need to open this back up: I think I may have misstated the problem set. The master list is *longer* than the detail list. They need to be flipped around in your solution. I need a *new* detail list that contains the values of all of the masters. I have edited the errors in my question.